# What encoding does nodejs use for arguments in child_process.spawn and child_process.execFile?

Tags: node.js, utf-8, character-encoding, child-process

In NodeJS, `child_process.execFile` and `.spawn` take this parameter:

- `args <string[]>` List of string arguments.

How does NodeJS encode the strings you pass in this array?

Context: I'm writing a nodejs app which adds metadata (often including non-ascii characters) to an mp3.

- I know that `ffmpeg` expects utf8-encoded arguments. If my nodejs app invokes `child_process.execFile("ffmpeg",["-metadata","title="+myString], {encoding:"utf8")` then how will nodejs encode `myString` in the arguments?
- I know that `id3v2` expects latin1-encoded arguments. If my nodejs app invokes `child_process.execFile("id3v2",["--titl",myString], {encoding:"latin1")` then how will nodejs encode `myString` in the arguments?

I see that `execFile` and `spawn` both take an "encoding" argument. But the nodejs docs say "The encoding option can be used to specify the character encoding used to decode the stdout and stderr output." The docs say nothing about the encoding of `args`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer: NodeJS always encodes the args as UTF-8.

I wrote a simplistic C++ app which shows the raw truth of the bytes that are passed into its argv:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("argc=%u\n", argc);
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
    printf("%u:\"", i);
    for (char *c = argv[i]; *c != 0; c++)
    {
      if (*c >= 32 && *c < 127)
        printf("%c", *c);
      else
      {
        unsigned char d = *(unsigned char *)c;
        unsigned int e = d;
        printf("\\x%02X", e);
      }
    }
    printf("\"\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Within my NodeJS app, I got some strings that I assuredly knew what they came from:

```
const a = Buffer.from([65]).toString("utf8");
const pound = Buffer.from([0xc2, 0xa3]).toString("utf8");
const skull = Buffer.from([0xe2, 0x98, 0xa0]).toString("utf8");

const pound2 = Buffer.from([0xa3]).toString("latin1");
```

The argument of toString indicates that the raw bytes in the buffer should be understood as if the buffer is in UTF-8 (or latin1 in the last case). The result is that I have four strings whose contents I unambiguously know is correct.

(I understand that Javascript VMs typically store their strings as UTF16? The fact that pound and pound2 behave the same in my experiments proves that the provenance of the strings doesn't matter.)

Finally I invoked execFile with these strings:

```
child_process.execFileAsync("argcheck",[a,pound,pound2,skull],{encoding:"utf8"});
child_process.execFileAsync("argcheck",[a,pound,pound2,skull],{encoding:"latin1"});
```

In both cases, the raw bytes that nodejs passed into argv were UTF-8 encodings of the strings `a`,`pound`,`pound2`,`skull`.

### So how can we pass latin1 arguments from nodejs?

The above explanation shows it's IMPOSSIBLE for nodejs to pass in any latin1 character in the range 127..255 to child_process.spawn/execFile. But there's an escape hatch involving child_process.exec:

- Example: this string "A £ ☠"
- stored internally in Javascript's UTF16 as "\u0041 \u00A3 \u2620"
- encoded in UTF-8 as "\x41 \xC2\xA3 \xE2\x98\xA0"
- encoded in latin1 as "\x41 \xA3 ?" (the skull-and-crossbones is inexpressible in latin1)
- Unicode chars 0-127 are same as latin1, and encode into utf-8 the same as latin1
- Unicode chars 128-255 are same as latin1, but encode differently
- Unicode chars 256+ don't exist in latin1/.

```
// this would encode them as utf8, which is wrong:
execFile("id3v2", ["--comment", "A £ ☠", "x.mp3"]);

// instead we'll use shell printf to bypass nodejs's wrongful encoding:
exec("id3v2 --comment \"`printf "A \xA3 ?"`\" x.mp3");
```

Here's a handy way to turn a string like "A £ ☠" into one like "A \xA3 ?", ready to pass into child_process.exec:

```
const comment2 = [...comment]
  .map(c =>
    c <= "\u007F" ? c : c <= "\u00FF"
    ? `\\x${("000" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-2)}` : "?")
    )
  .join("");

const cmd = `id3v2 --comment \"\`printf \"${comment2}\"\`\" \"${fn}\"`;

child_process.exec(cmd, (e, stdout, stderr) => { ... });
```